# _doPostBack method is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback

I have a scenario in which i have to do a postback and after that i have to redirect it to some other page the thing page is in iframe so i have to redirect it in the parent so have to do it client side.

some code

```
function CallResponseList(){
    var hfRefID = document.getElementById('<%=hfRefID.ClientID %>');
    $("#hdnResponse").val(1);
    __doPostBack('<%= lbtest.UniqueID %>',null);
    window.parent.location.href='ResponseList.aspx?ref=1&surveyID=2 
    HideChartPopup();
 }
```

the problem is: it work fine with IE but in Firefox. It did not wait for the response of post back and redirect it to other page.

How to make it wait for the response in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers does not automaticaly generate the `__doPostBack` function. You can manualy add it to your page to avoid such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I Suppose the Page Execution stops in line 1 after you do a postback[which Firefox is doing now]

```
__doPostBack('<%= lbtest.UniqueID %>',null);
window.parent.location.href='ResponseList.aspx?ref=1&surveyID=2
```

i don't have a clue as to why IE goes to execute the next line, where it redirects to another page with query string. You could step into the function and check with FireBug. 'FireBug' is your partner in webdevelopment.